# SQLiteException Handle

Tags: c#, sqlite, exception

How right to handle exception with the one type but with different sense ?

For example:

SQLiteException is thrown 
if table not exist, 
if row not exist, 
if impossible to open DB file etc.
and handlers for each one should be different, but standart way

```
try{ } catch (SQLiteException e) { }
```

doesn't work to make many handler, because code is one for each.

Can i use message of exception ? (IMHO it is not right)

or

Should i check each question as 
file exist, table exist, column exist, row exist etc.

Comment: Are you going to perform different logic in the `catch` block depending on the specific problem? Like, if the column is missing are you going to write code to add it and then try the operation again? Or are you just going to log/alert the exception?

Comment: @Crowcoder yes, i doing some logic like add new table, column

Comment: I don't use Sqlite much so I don't know how it reports errors but I would expect the Exception to contain an error code like SQL Server will report error codes. They are listed here: https://sqlite.org/rescode.html